# Why there are dead tuples in insert-only table?

Tags: postgresql

I have an insert-only table where rows are never deleted or updated.
I use `INSERT ...ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` statement to insert data.
But still, there is a small, but growing number of dead tuples:

```
select pg_stat_get_dead_tuples(16385);
 pg_stat_get_dead_tuples
-------------------------
                    7248
(1 row)

select pg_stat_get_dead_tuples(16385);
 pg_stat_get_dead_tuples
-------------------------
                    7250
(1 row)
```

I'm pretty sure that there are no update or delete or upsert statements in the code.
Are there any other explanations for the dead tuples in that table?